# Restart the computer from command prompt

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I'm working with the prompt command, and I want to know of it is possibile to restart the computer with command prompt

Comment: Answered for you, but this was something you could of easily found with a quick Google search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Just type `shutdown /r` in command prompt and it should reboot after a minute.